# Autofocus not working on Canon 20D

Tags: canon, autofocus, camera

i have a Canon 20D and i cannot get the autofocus to function correctly. Whenever i try to autofocus the lens will go to the closest focus and stay there. If i press the shutter button again it will move slightly and stop in the same place. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Does this happen with more than one lens?

Comment: yes. Also, the lenses I've used on it work fully on multiple other bodies.

Comment: Did it just start happening suddenly?

Answer (score 4):

> How can i fix this issue?

You probably can't. But here are a few things you can try:

- Clean the electronic contacts on the camera that connect to the electronic contacts on your lenses
- Reset the camera to factory default settings.
- Remove the battery and leave it out for several hours or even a couple of days. Also remove the button cell backup battery that preserves the time/date and selected settings when the battery is removed. Don't forget to reset the time and date when you replace the backup battery and the main battery and power the camera back up.

Beyond that there's not much you can do if you've already confirmed that all the lenses work fine on other EOS bodies and none of them work on the 20D. Sending it in for servicing isn't practical since any evaluation, much less a repair, will cost more than the camera is worth. So at that point it's probably time to start thinking about a replacement camera body.

Comment: Long shot, but could there be an issue with the shutter button? And if so, is back button focus a work around?

Comment: That depends on whether the camera properly meters on a shutter half-press or not. If metering is working as expected that eliminates the shutter button as the source of the issue. This really sounds like a major hardware issue with the PDAF system.